# Get Data Point from OxyPlot ScatterPlot

Tags: c#, winforms, oxyplot

I would like to know how I can get (specifically), just the x-coordinate of a scatterplot that I've plotted using OxyPlot.

```
//user clicks on graph line data...
//x-coordinate gets assigned to variable
int x = ...
```

I'm using winforms.

EDIT:

```
   private void plotView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        plotView.ActualModel.Series[0].MouseDown += (s, e0) =>
        {
            if (e0.ChangedButton != OxyMouseButton.Left)
                return;
            else
                pointx = (int)e0.HitTestResult.NearestHitPoint.X;
        };
    }
```

WORKING CODE:

```
        s0.MouseDown += (s, e0) =>
        {
            if (e0.ChangedButton == OxyMouseButton.Left)
            {
                var item = e0.HitTestResult.Item as ScatterPoint;
                if (item != null)
                {
                    pointx = (int)item.X;
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach to the mouse down event for your series like so:

```
var model = new PlotModel { Title = "Test Mouse Events" };

var s1 = new LineSeries();
model.Series.Add(s1);

double x;

s1.MouseDown += (s, e) =>
            {
                x = e.Position.X;
            };
```

Adapted from their sample code found here: https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/09fc7c50e080f702315a51af57a70d7a47024040/Source/Examples/ExampleLibrary/Examples/MouseEventExamples.cs

and demonstrated here: http://resources.oxyplot.org/examplebrowser/ => scroll down to Mouse Events

EDIT: I found out that the position you get from x is a screen coordinate that you have to convert to find the correct axis point like so:

```
x = (s as LineSeries).InverseTransform(e0.Position).X;
```

Comment: I need to this in a Mouse Click event though, and when I do, I get an error that says `'e' cannot be declared in this scope`, so I rename it to `e0`. When I do that, I always get a zero for x. How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe try making int x a double so it doesn't truncate any double values to 0. Aside from that you could edit your code in and I could look at exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Oh, if you're looking for the actual coordinate clicked (not the point like I may have presumed) do: "e0.Position.X"

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for exact coordinates of a scatter plot (graph) clicked. What do you mean by, do: - ?

Comment: And I've tried making int x both a double and int. It shows values for both, but they're waaaaay off from actual values.

Comment: I've edited my question to show what I'm doing in the click event. I've also tried using `e0.Position.X`. Unfortunately I get the same results as with the edited code I've posted. When I click on X Datapoint value 794, I get 560 in variable x, when I click 600, I get 474, when I click 208, I get 300.etc. And I don't understand why :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92895/discussion-between-zachary-and-john).

Comment: I've solved it! I've added the working code. Thank you:)